# iTunes Connect error(Application Loader error)

Tags: app-store

I am uploading an application on appstore,when i upload the build in Application Loader under the processing in iTunes Connect, i face an error given as below. please give me the detail to solve this problem.

ERROR -- "Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate."

To  solve the issue i just try to create a new certificate. But i got a new problem in the process of creating a new certificate that is as given "Generating a Certificate Signing Request go to next step to Submitting a Certificate Signing Request For Approval,In this step After creating a CSR, log in to the iOS Provisioning Portal and navigate to ‘Certificates’ -> ‘Distribution’ and click the ‘Add Certificate’ button. But still there is no button like "Add Certificate" display on my screen.

Please tell me the proper way to solve this issue.